# different CSS animation on load and on hover

Tags: css, animation

I have an animation that happens when the page loads. I want to animate that same element on hover. However, then I mouse off again, the original transition is played again. How can I keep the opacity on mouse-off to 100% so that flash in the middle doesn't happen?

http://jsfiddle.net/edlea/qN2T4/

HTML

```
<div class="bubble animated"></div>
```

CSS

```
.bubble{
    background-color:#000;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;

    /* INITIAL ANIMATION ON PAGE LOAD */
    -webkit-animation-name: bounceIn;
    -moz-animation-name: bounceIn;
    -o-animation-name: bounceIn;
    animation-name: bounceIn;
}

/* THIS IS WHAT I WANT ON HOVER */
.bubble:hover{
    -webkit-animation-name: blob;
    -moz-animation-name: blob;
    -o-animation-name: blob;
    animation-name: blob;

    -webkit-animation-duration:0.5s;
    -moz-animation-duration:0.5s;
    -ms-animation-duration:0.5s;
    -o-animation-duration:0.5s;
    animation-duration:0.5s;

    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-timing-function: ease;

    cursor:pointer;
}






/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
/* Animations                */
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * */


.animated{
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode:both;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode:both;
    -o-animation-fill-mode:both;
    animation-fill-mode:both;

    -webkit-animation-duration:0.5s;
    -moz-animation-duration:0.5s;
    -ms-animation-duration:0.5s;
    -o-animation-duration:0.5s;
    animation-duration:0.5s;
}



/* * * * * * * blob * * * * * * */
@-webkit-keyframes blob {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes blob {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes blob {
    0% {
        -o-transform: scale(1);
    }
    100% {
        -o-transform: scale(1.2);
    }
}
@keyframes blob {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }
}

/* * * * * * * bounceIn * * * * * * */

@-webkit-keyframes bounceIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(.1);
    }
    30% {

        -webkit-transform: scale(1.15);
    }

    60% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(.9);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes bounceIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: scale(.1);
    }
    30% {

        -moz-transform: scale(1.15);
    }

    60% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: scale(.9);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
    }
}

@-o-keyframes bounceIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-transform: scale(.1);
    }
    30% {

        -o-webkit-transform: scale(1.15);
    }

    60% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-webkit-transform: scale(.9);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
}

@keyframes bounceIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(.1);
    }
    30% {

        transform: scale(1.15);
    }

    60% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(.9);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The animation that you are setting for the hover state can be achieved thru transitions. (just set the transform in the hover state, and the transition delay in the base)

It will be easier to manage, and when you go back to the un-hover state the animation won't run again.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with jquery

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qN2T4/7/)

here's the jquery code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
// Handler for .ready() called.

$(".bubble").hover(function() {
    $(".bubble").removeClass("animated");
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try showing the animation only on page load. For this add a class in the div like this:-

```
 <div id="preload_div" class="preload bubble animated"></div>
```

Change the animation from this:

```
.bubble{
    background-color:#000;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;

    /* INITIAL ANIMATION ON PAGE LOAD */
    -webkit-animation-name: bounceIn;
    -moz-animation-name: bounceIn;
    -o-animation-name: bounceIn;
    animation-name: bounceIn;
}
```

to

```
.bubble{
    background-color:#000;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;

}

.preload.bubble{
    /* INITIAL ANIMATION ON PAGE LOAD */
    -webkit-animation-name: bounceIn;
    -moz-animation-name: bounceIn;
    -o-animation-name: bounceIn;
    animation-name: bounceIn;
}
```

After loading the page remove the 'preload' class, like this:-

```
 window.onload = function(){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    document.getElementById('preload_div').classList.remove('preload');   
                }, 200)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a codepen with 1 animation with CSS and 1 with two lines of jQuery to fix the page load issue.

https://codepen.io/MateoStabio/pen/jOVvwrM

If you do not want the CSS animation on page load, you will need to use a tiny little script of JS that styles the element with the OUT animation only after the element has been hovered for the first time. We will do this by adding a class of .wasHovered to the element and style the added class with the OUT Animation.

jQuery:

```
$("svg").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).addClass("wasHovered");
 });
```

CSS:

```
svg path{

}

svg.wasHovered path{
    animation: animateLogoOut 1s;
}

svg:hover path{
    animation: animateLogoIn 1s;
}

@keyframes animateLogoIn {
    from {stroke-dashoffset: -510px;}
    to {stroke-dashoffset: 0px;}
}
@keyframes animateLogoOut {
    from {stroke-dashoffset: 0px;}
    to {stroke-dashoffset: -510px;}
}
```